# ckeditor value equals result of dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm wanting to have a dropdown on my form, the options will be titles to content in my database, I want the content to show in a ckeditor when delected.

I'm looking to do something like the below with jquery and need a little help.

if 'dropdown' value is not 'please select'
CKeditor value equals php variable from database.
end statement

I'm fairly happy getting the variables in php so just need some jquery to change the ckeditor value dependant on the dropdown not being defaulted.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html:**

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
</select>
<div id="result" style="border:1px solid #000;padding:10px;color:#ff0000;display:none;"></div>
```

**jQuery** dont forget to include the jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).val();
    $.get('select.php', {select:option}, function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

**your php file (select.php)**

```
if(!empty($_GET['select'])) {
    //call database and bring back the content for this selection and echo it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to populate the "option" elements of your select box using php, which I believe you said you are comfortable with.

Then, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myCKEditorTextArea').text($('#mySelectBox').val());
});
```

for pre-population on page load, or:

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function(){
        $('#myCKEditorTextArea').text($(this).val());
 });
```

for population when the user changes the select box value.